# data check before leaving view via Back-Button in navigationbar in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have set up an app for iOS (iPad) with different views as split view in Xcode 12. The individual pages are linked via the navigation bar.

In one view I have the chance to type in data, which can be stored via a dedicated button. However, there is still the chance to leave the view via the back-button in the navigation bar without having stored the changed data first.

Hence, I want to check before leaving the view via the back-button, if there are still some unsaved data changes and if yes, I want to ask the user if these changes should be stored via an UIAlert-Dialogue.

Setting up this UIAlertDialogue in the viewWillDisappear() doesn't work since the view it is too late.

Hence, I tried to handle these via an overriding definition of the navigationItem.backBarButtonItem in the viewDidLoad(). But this doesn't work either - see code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.target = self
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.action = #selector(checkDataChange)
    }


    
    @objc func checkDataChange() {
        if unsavedData {
            let checkSaving = UIAlertController(title: "Unsaved data", message: "Do you want to store them?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let saveChanges = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) {(alertAction) in self.saveChanges()}
            let discardChanges = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default) {(alertAction) in self.closeView()}
            checkSaving.addAction(saveChanges)
            checkSaving.addAction(discardChanges)
            self.present(checkSaving, animated: false, completion: nil)
       }

            
    }
```

Can you please help me, what I have to change so that it works? Thanks for your valuable support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom bar button into navigation controller.

Set back bar button for view controller...

```
func setBackButton() {
    let btnBack = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnBack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25)
    btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_back"), for: .normal)
    btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBackTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
}
```

Add back btn selector method

```
@objc func btnBackTapped() {
    //show user an alert for the unsaved data or you can pop/dismiss the view controller
}
```

I have created an extension...

```
extension UIViewController {

 var isModal: Bool {

    let presentingIsModal = presentingViewController != nil
    let presentingIsNavigation = navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController
    let presentingIsTabBar = tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController

    return presentingIsModal || presentingIsNavigation || presentingIsTabBar
  }

//----------------------------------------------------------

  func setBackButton() {
    let btnBack = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnBack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25)
    btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_white"), for: .normal)
    btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBackTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
  }

//----------------------------------------------------------

  @objc func btnBackTapped() {
    if !isModal {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    } else {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the above extension like below...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setBackButton()
}
```

If you want to override back button selector method then you can do like this.

```
 override func btnBackTapped() {
    //do your stuff here...show alert for unsaved data    
    super.btnBackTapped()
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like by adding a custom back button.
If you want to add button like back arrow you can use the images.

1. backArrow@1x.png      [image]
2. backArrow@2x.png [image]
3. backArrow@3x.png [image]

Here is the Code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backArrow") , style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backAction(sender:)))
    customBackButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton
}

func backAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // custom actions here
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very valuable